# Problem with apt-get update on Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux, macintosh

I'm using Kali, and my Mac Book Pro has some problems with the Wi-Fi monitoring, so I tried to solve them, but when I type the command 
`apt-get update` this appears:

```
Ign:1 debian.org/debian main InRelease
Err:2 .jp.debian.org/debian main Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ftp.jp.debian.org/debian main Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: sorry for my Inglis I'm Italian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [`sources.list`](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) should contain only the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Open the terminal and run the following command:

```
echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 12):

[You should not be using a Debian repository](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) for Kali Linux.

Either use a Kali repository, or switch away from Kali to a different distribution.

Since you're a beginner it would make a lot of sense to consider a beginner's distribution. [Kali is not a beginner's distribution](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux). Instead, I would recommend Mint, Ubuntu or Fedora (but this is not an exhaustive list).

Answer (score 1):

Remove debian main PPA it seems not supported to do that

1. open software and update app
2. go to other software tab
3. uncheck the debian main ppa
4. click revert

if you don't have software and update app in your kali machine remove ppa from the terminal

1. open terminal
2. `sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
3. `sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/(replace_with_PPA_Name).list`

then `sudo apt-get update` and tell me what happen with you